# Is there any input for which selection sort outperforms bubble sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

I mean like...partial, full or reverse sorted arrays.

I have already tried the following: random, fully sorted, almost sorted, partially sorted, rever sorted and the count of bubble is lesser when it's fully sorted. In all other cases, it's the same.

```
int selectionSort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= r; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[min]) min = j;
            count++;
        }   
        if (i != min) swap(a[i], a[min]);
    }
    return count;
}


int bubbleSort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int count = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = r; j > i; j--) {
            if (a[j-1] > a[j]) {
                if (flag == false) flag = true;
                swap(a[j - 1], a[j]);
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (flag == false) break;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The count returns the number of comparisons BTW.

Comment: *"I mean like...partial, full or reverse sorted arrays."* - you've got ideas about what *might* be faster in selection sort, and code ready to sort with, why don't you make some actual measurements for large arrays with the various pre-sorted data you're speculating on? Next, I'd suggest having your code count the number of comparisons *and the number of element exchanges/swaps*, so you can reason about what would be faster for element types where one of those operations was far more expensive than the other, so you can make conclusions valid for types other than `int`.

Comment: It said my question was mostly code.

Comment: @TonyD: If you see my question, I'm counting the number of comparisons. Is there any input for which the count for selections sort is less than that for bubble sort?

Comment: @South: *after* you measuring sorting the data sets you've already thought of to see if they provide an example of selection sort being faster, *then* it's reasonable to ask us to make an effort.

Comment: There are few inputs for which selection sort or indeed any sort *doesn't* outperform bubble sort. Bubble sort is just a teaching aid, an academic curiosity. It shouldn't be used in real code.

Comment: @TonyD: I have already tried the following: random, fully sorted, almost sorted, partially sorted, rever sorted and the count of bubble is lesser when it's fully sorted. In all other cases, it's the same. This is my effort.

Comment: @South: nice!  Why don't you edit that information into the question, ideally along with some simple input sets for those cases and the counts/output, and the full program so other people can cut/paste it into their compilers and reproduce your results / evolve your code?  Then you should stop getting downvotes and get more concrete help....

Answer (score 1):

> Among simple average-case Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithms, selection sort almost always outperforms bubble sort.

[Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Comment: How? Can we prove it using some input? I'm counting the number of comparisons in my code.

Comment: @South You can prove it with almost any input. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I hinted at this already in comments, but here's some updated code for you that counts both comparisons and exchanges/swaps, and illustrates that for some random input the ***number of exchanges/swaps*** is where selection sort outperforms bubble sort.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

struct Stats { int swaps_ = 0, compares_ = 0; };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stats& s)
{
    return os << "{ swaps " << s.swaps_
              << ", compares " << s.compares_ << " }";   
}

Stats selectionSort(std::vector<int>& a, int l, int r) {
    Stats stats;
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= r; j++) {
            if (a.at(j) < a.at(min)) min = j;
            ++stats.compares_;
        }   
        if (i != min) {
            swap(a.at(i), a.at(min));
            ++stats.swaps_;
        }
    }
    return stats;
}


Stats bubbleSort(std::vector<int>& a, int l, int r) {
    Stats stats;
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = r; j > i; j--) {
            if (a.at(j-1) > a.at(j)) {
                if (flag == false) flag = true;
                swap(a.at(j - 1), a.at(j));
                ++stats.swaps_;
            }
            ++stats.compares_;
        }
        if (flag == false) break;
    }
    return stats;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ 4, 8, 3, 8, 10, -1, 3, 20, 5 };

    std::vector<int> v1s = v1;
    std::cout << "sel " << selectionSort(v1s, 0, v1s.size() - 1);

    std::vector<int> v1b = v1;
    std::cout << ", bub " << bubbleSort(v1b, 0, v1b.size() - 1) << '\n';
    assert(v1s == v1b);
    // always a good idea to check the code's doing what you expect...
    for (int i : v1s) std::cout << i << ' ';
       std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
sel { swaps 6, compares 36 }, bub { swaps 15, compares 36 }

-1 3 3 4 5 8 8 10 20
```

You can observe / copy / fork-and-edit / run the code online [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b080446679a945d6).